# Не устанавливается библиотека Pillow для Python 3

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, установка, pillow

Пользуюсь системой Ubuntu 16.04.1 (сервер).

При вводе `pip install pillow` идет установка, но в конце выдаёт ошибку:

```
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
 ----------------------------------------
 Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-2MM32Z/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-MVcbrz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2MM32Z/pillow/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в системные области ставить, используйте:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-imaging
```

Ubuntu упаковывает `pillow` библиотеку под этим именем в современных версиях.

Если хотите из исходников ставить (например, в virtualenv), то поставьте заголовки python, С зависимости такие как libjpeg. Список зависимостей [в инструкции по установке посмотрите](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/installation.html#building-from-source). Или выполните:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep python3-imaging
```

а затем заново компиляцию запустите.

Answer (score 0):

Чистая система или виртуалка?

Наверно, не хватает зависимостей, попробуйте выполнить команду для установки заголовочных файлов Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Comment: `root@finansov14:~# apt-get install python-dev
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.11-1).
python-dev установлен вручную.
Возможно, для исправления этих ошибок вы захотите воспользоваться «apt-get -f install»:
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libjpeg8-dev : Зависит: libjpeg8 (= 8d-1+deb7u1) но 8c-2ubuntu8 будет установлен
E: Неудовлетворённые зависимости. Попытайтесь выполнить «apt-get -f install», не указывая имени пакета, (или найдите другое решение).`

Comment: @MaxSnegirev вот, выполните sudo apt-get -f install, затем снова пробуйте pillow, а там будем смотреть по результатам